# What is the meaning of "rake in the bucks"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've read the phrase in [a post by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000054.html):

> You should be starting to get some ideas about how to break the chicken and egg problem: provide a backwards compatibility mode which either delivers a truckload of chickens, or a truckload of eggs, depending on how you look at it, and sit back and **rake in the bucks**.

I somehow feel that the meaning is:

- You earn so much money that you have to collect them with a rake.

or

- You will see money as leaves on the ground (because you have so much of it) and you will collect them with a rake.

We have an equivalent phrase in our language (Persian) that refers to someone who has a lot of money, and says he **shovels the money**.

How much am I right?

Comment: Quite right.  Both your explanations are similar and correct interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression that means *earn a lot of money*.
Sit back and rake in the buck, that is relax and bring home the money.

[Rake in](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rake+in):

> - earn large sums of money; "Since she accepted the new position, she has been raking it in"

[Buck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bucks):

( Informal)

> - A dollar.
> - An amount of money: working overtime to make an extra buck.

(TFD)

Comment: *buck* is countable (rake in the bucks)